# Navigating through an applet with Card Layout (Need some guidance and code fixing)

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe, cardlayout

First of all I would like to say that in terms of my java knowledge I am a total beginner. So, I am developing an applet which would have different pages using Card Layout. I managed to gather some code from an online sources, however, I am struggling to accomplish a few things. I will split it into questions.

1. How do I make it so that when the button is pressed, the user would be taken to a specified card rather than a next one?
2. In the 'Main' class, how do I set visibility to a card that I want rather than the first one on the list?
3. In pages classes (Menu, FirstPage, etc), how can I only have a single method for button handling rather than having to repeat the same code?
4. Will my page classes work if I will have paint methods in them?
5. How do I turn this application into an applet? As at the moment it is a JFrame.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

Main class

```
 public class Main
{
    private Menu menu;
    private FirstPage page1;
    private SecondPage page2;
    private ThirdPage page3;
    private FourthPage page4;

    private void showGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout());
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(240,600));

        menu = new Menu(contentPane);
        page1 = new FirstPage(contentPane);
        page2 = new SecondPage(contentPane);
        page3 = new ThirdPage(contentPane);
        page4 = new FourthPage(contentPane);

        contentPane.add(menu, "Menu"); 
        contentPane.add(page1, "First page");
        contentPane.add(page2, "Second page");
        contentPane.add(page3, "Third page");
        contentPane.add(page4, "Fourth page");

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);      
        frame.pack();   
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new Main().showGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Menu page class

```
class Menu extends javax.swing.JPanel 
{
    private javax.swing.JLabel textLabel;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton pageOne;
    private JButton pageTwo;
    private JButton pageThree;
    private JButton pageFour;

    public Menu(JPanel cp) 
    {
        this.contentPane = cp;
          initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() 
    {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setLayout(null);

        textLabel = new JLabel("This is the menu page", JLabel.CENTER);
        textLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        pageOne = new JButton("Flowers");
        pageTwo = new JButton("Trees");
        pageThree = new JButton("Rivers");
        pageFour = new JButton("Seas");


        pageOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ @Override  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { pageOneAction(ae); } });
        pageTwo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ @Override  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { pageTwoAction(ae); } });
        pageThree.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ @Override  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { pageThreeAction(ae); } });
        pageFour.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ @Override  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { pageFourAction(ae); } });
        textLabel.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 60);

        pageOne.setBounds(20, 100, 200, 60);
        pageTwo.setBounds(20, 170, 200, 60);
        pageThree.setBounds(20, 240, 200, 60);
        pageFour.setBounds(20, 310, 200, 60);

        add(pageOne);
        add(pageTwo);
        add(pageThree);
        add(pageFour);
        add(textLabel);
    }                   

    private void pageOneAction(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)contentPane.getLayout();
        layout.next(contentPane); 
    }
    private void pageTwoAction(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)contentPane.getLayout();
        layout.next(contentPane); 
    }
    private void pageThreeAction(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)contentPane.getLayout();
        layout.next(contentPane); 
    }
    private void pageFourAction(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)contentPane.getLayout();
        layout.next(contentPane); 
    }
}
```

First page class

```
class FirstPage extends javax.swing.JPanel 
{
    private javax.swing.JLabel textLabel;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton menu;
    private JButton pageTwo;
    private JButton pageThree;
    private JButton pageFour;

    public FirstPage(JPanel cp) 
    {
        this.contentPane = cp;
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() 
    {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setLayout(null);

        textLabel = new JLabel("This is the flowers page", JLabel.CENTER);
        textLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

        menu = new JButton("Back to Menu");
        pageTwo = new JButton("Trees");
        pageThree = new JButton("Rivers");
        pageFour = new JButton("Seas");


        menu.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ @Override  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { menuAction(ae); } });
        pageTwo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ @Override  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { pageTwoAction(ae); } });
        pageThree.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ @Override  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { pageThreeAction(ae); } });
        pageFour.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ @Override  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { pageFourAction(ae); } });

        textLabel.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 60);
        menu.setBounds(20, 100, 200, 60);
        pageTwo.setBounds(20, 170, 200, 60);
        pageThree.setBounds(20, 240, 200, 60);
        pageFour.setBounds(20, 310, 200, 60);

        add(menu);
        add(pageTwo);
        add(pageThree);
        add(pageFour);
        add(textLabel);
    }                   

    private void menuAction(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)contentPane.getLayout();
        layout.next(contentPane); 
    }
    private void pageTwoAction(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)contentPane.getLayout();
        layout.next(contentPane); 
    }
    private void pageThreeAction(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)contentPane.getLayout();
        layout.next(contentPane); 
    }
    private void pageFourAction(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        CardLayout layout = (CardLayout)contentPane.getLayout();
        layout.next(contentPane); 
    }
}
```

The other pages are the same as the ones above.

Comment: SO is a Q&A site, not a help desk. It works best with one specific question (alluded to in the title) with one specific and (ultimately accepted) answer. I'm voting to close this '5 question smorgasbord' as 'too broad'.

Comment: But I will, in comments, address *"How do I turn this application into an applet?"* See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: I need to use an applet.

Comment: Why instead of helping you are just wasting your and my time while being mean? This will certainly not gonna help me to learn anything. I asked quite specific questions that can be answered in a few lines of code and few sentences explaining how it works. If you're not intending to offer any guidance or help please, again, do not waste your and my time and simply do not comment. People like you should not exist in the programming community. Trying to feel important by insulting new learners is the most ridiculous thing which makes people upset and not want to expand their knowledge further.